# How to configure kafka consumer so that during after autoscaling the total number of messages fetched remain same?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let's say I have a consumer running which is fetching from 10 partitions. In one poll request the consumer fetches 10 records per partition so 100 records in total.

Now after adding one more consumer to the group and rebalancing both consumers are fetching from 5 partitions and each consumer is now fetching 50 records in total(10 per partition).

I want to know if there's a way we can configure Kafka Consumer so that even after adding one more consumer both the consumers starts fetching 20 records per partition so that total remains 100.

I tried using max.poll.records and fetch.max.bytes but it didn't work for me.
After setting fetch.max.bytes to say 1000 kafka was fetching 25 records from partitions.
And after setting max.poll.records to say 50 each partition had 25 max records during poll so 250 records for 10 partitions. I want to keep the records to 50 overall. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct configuration you can set to tell the KafkaConsumer how many messages exactly it should fetch.

I am sure there are other solutions but I see the following two options:

- If you have the knowledge of the messages sizes and the messages have roughly identical byte size, use `fetch.min.bytes` together with `fetch.max.wait.ms` to get the minimal required messages. Adjusting the `max.poll.records` you can try to get to the exact required number.
- Use `seek` of the KafkaConsumer to tell the consumer exactly to which offset position per partition it should fetch the data on the next `poll`. The `seek` API is described in the JavaDocs of the [KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek-org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition-long-) as "Overrides the fetch offsets that the consumer will use on the next poll(timeout). If this API is invoked for the same partition more than once, the latest offset will be used on the next poll(). Note that you may lose data if this API is arbitrarily used in the middle of consumption, to reset the fetch offsets".

Comment: Thanks mike. But even if I use seek to fetch messages in one consumer after scaling the partitions are divided so the total number of messages will also reduce right ? Because the seek parameter is same. And I think first approach also have the same caveat.

Comment: the seek method can be used at a TopicPartition. So you would need to shut down your two consumers, implement the new logic and then start them again. At the moment I do not see an "easy" path to achieve what you are trying to do. You are right, that both options are not straight-forward and bring some caveats. At least, I am not aware of any easy option...